# R data.table explode column using tstrsplit

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I have the following `data.table` as an example

```
df = data.table(id = c(1, 2, 3), val=c("['hello', 'world']", "['hi']", "['so', 'there']"))
```

I want to split the list like object into separate rows with the `id` repeated. So the expected `data.table` I want is the following

```
df2 = data.table(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), val=c("hello", "world", "hi", "so", "there"))
```

I tried the following

```
df[, c("test") := tstrsplit(val, ",", fixed=TRUE)]
```

However, I got the following error

> Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(c("test"), tstrsplit(val, ",",
> fixed = TRUE))) :    Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 3 items of
> column 'test'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to
> make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are these actually strings in `df$val` or is this a list column?

Comment: You do not need `fixed`. also you should wrap the result in a list. ie `df[, .(test=tstrsplit(val, ',')), by = id]`

Comment: `fixed` is probably preferable even if it's not needed

Comment: Yes, these are strings within ```df$val```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the structure of the data you have, it seems you have a python dataset. You could use `reticulate` for this:

```
library(reticulate)
ast <- import('ast')

df_python <- r_to_py(df)
df_python$assign(val = df_python$val$transform(ast$literal_eval))$explode('val')

    id    val
0  1.0  hello
0  1.0  world
1  2.0     hi
2  3.0     so
2  3.0  there
```

Directly you could do:

```
df[, .(val = tstrsplit(gsub('[^a-z,]', '',val), ',')), by = 'id']
   id   val
1:  1 hello
2:  1 world
3:  2    hi
4:  3    so
5:  3 there
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way,

```r
df[, .(val = tstrsplit(gsub("[][']", "", val), ",", fixed=TRUE)), by = id]
#       id    val
#    <num> <list>
# 1:     1  hello
# 2:     1  world
# 3:     2     hi
# 4:     3     so
# 5:     3  there
```

It removes all square-brackets and single-quotes, then concatenates all `val` strings into a single string (`,`-collapsed), then `tstrsplit`s them as originally intended. The `by=id` ensures that we don't inadvertently combine different `val`s, and that `id` is preserved in the output.

If you wanted to see the grouping, combining, then splitting in steps, then one could do

```r
df1[, .(val = paste(gsub("[][']", "", val), collapse = ",")), by = id]
#       id          val
#    <num>       <char>
# 1:     1 hello, world
# 2:     2           hi
# 3:     3    so, there
df1[, .(val = paste(gsub("[][']", "", val), collapse = ",")), by = id
  ][, .(val = tstrsplit(val, ",", fixed = TRUE)), by = id]
#       id    val
#    <num> <list>
# 1:     1  hello
# 2:     1  world
# 3:     2     hi
# 4:     3     so
# 5:     3  there
```

Note that the error's recommendation to `rep(id,...)` is fine, except you'll need to do a little more work to know how many times to repeat each `id`; using it as a grouping variable relieves this need, at a small expense of execution time (since it does the `tstrsplit` once for each group instead of all together).

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we may use `str_extract_all` with `unnest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(val = str_extract_all(val, '\\w+')) %>%
  unnest(val)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id val  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 hello
2     1 world
3     2 hi   
4     3 so   
5     3 there
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `eval` + `str2lang`

```
> df[, .(val = eval(str2lang(gsub("\\[(.*)\\]", "c(\\1)", val)))), id]
   id   val
1:  1 hello
2:  1 world
3:  2    hi
4:  3    so
5:  3 there
```

Comment: Looks like an inexpensive `jsonlite::fromJSON` or similar. I'm not always a fan of `eval` in production, this doesn't look too bad. Nice.

Comment: @r2evans I would say is is only one option, but not recommended due to its efficiency (especially for long strings)